# Blank PDF when returning it as a byte array in a HttpResponseMessage from web API

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

so I am having this weird issue where I am trying to display a pdf that I am receiving from my web API, but the pdf shows blank in the new browser tab in Chrome (IE is showing nothing, but it console.logs the ajax success callback).

The API sends it back to my ajax request like so:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetPdf(PdfModel model)
        {
            var pdf = await _pdfManager.GetPdfAsync(model);

            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdf);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "MyPdf.pdf";
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

            return response;
        }
```

This is the GetPdfAsync method that is calling out to another API to get the pdf.  When I use Postman to call the api with the same model, I do get a PDF that displays as the response, so I know that works fine.

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetPdfAsync(PdfModel, CancellationToken ct = new CancellationToken())
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = PdfGeneratorApiUrl;

                var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
                const string endpoint = "myPdf/pdf";

                var response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), ct);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

In My ajax call this is how I am trying to display it, but when I am opening the pdf in the new tab it shows a blank pdf with the filename I gave it in the ajax success.  Although in the console.log the blob.size = 1053248.

```
 $.ajax({
         url: '/n/api/getPdf',
         type: 'POST',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         responseType: 'arraybuffer',
         data: JSON.stringify(getPdfRequest),
         success: function (data) {
             var blob = new Blob([data]);
             console.log(blob.size);
             var link=document.createElement('a');
             link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
             link.download="MyPdf.pdf";
             link.click();
         },
         error: function (data) {
             console.log(data);
         }
  });
```

Comment: Hi man, I know that a long time has passed since you posted this issue, but now I'm facing the same problem and I just could not find a solution. How did you solve that?

Comment: @RicardoAlves I can't recall as of right now, I'll give it some thought and  be sure to come back and let you know if it pops back into my mind.